# Vuetify data table :item-class doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm really confused by ":item-class" prop in Vuetify (v. 2.3.4) data table. It does nothing even if I try to add a static text class.

```
<v-data-table class="mt-10"
                      item-key="id"
                      :headers="headers"
                      :items="user_tender_assignment_table.user_tender_assignments"
                      :loading="user_tender_assignment_table.loading"
                      :loading-text="tables.loading_text"
                      :search="user_tender_assignment_table.search"
                      v-model="user_tender_assignment_table.selected"
                      :footer-props="tables.footer_props"
                      :item-class="'xxx'"
</v-data-table>
```

It just renders `tr` tags without any class:

[image]

Do you know why? I think it worked some time ago and I haven't changed Vuetify (2) version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`item-class` does not specify the CSS classes directly. If it is a String - then it specifies the property inside the item's Object which contains the CSS class(es). If it is a Function - then it gets the `item` as its argument and must return the CSS class(es).

Comment: Per @jssDev "it is essential to have Vuetify updated at least at v2.3.8"  I was only v2.1.0 and it did not work until I updated

Comment: Thanks! `:item-class="() => 'myClass'"`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `item-class` like below:

`<template>`:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :item-class="rowClass"
></v-data-table>
```

`<script>`:

```
methods: {
    rowClass(item) {
        console.log(item)
        const rowClass = 'myclass'
        return rowClass;
    }
}
```

`<style>`:

```
<style lang="css">
.myclass {
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: WORKS! Thank you. I was looking for some clean solution this helped me a lot :)

Comment: For Vuetify 3 see this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77613625/14967413).

Comment: I tried to use the item-class to update the font-size. Didn't work. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I choose string type for item-class, then you can pass any CSS class name as a prop in your items object. it's like this in a simplified way:

> Template:

```
<v-data-table
     :headers="headers"
     :items="lineas"
      item-class="color"
      ...
</v-data-table>
```

> Data object:

```
data: () => ({
     lineas: [
       {text: 'Fecha',align: 'start',sortable: true,value: 'fecha', color: 'red-line'},
       {text: 'Descripción',align: 'start',sortable: false,value: 'descripcion', color: 'blue-line'},
      ],
})
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .blue-line td {
        color: green;
    }

    .red-line td{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

In order for it to work properly, it is essential to have Vuetify updated at least at v2.3.8, as this feature was recently included (May '2020):
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/11254

Answer (score 2):

Vueitfy3 has now a `v-data-table` **`cell-props`** property that can be populated by a function.

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"          
    :cell-props="getCellProps"
>
```

With, considering items as array of object with a price value, a test function like this:

```
function getCellProps (data) {
    if (data.item.price > 25) {
       return { class: 'text-error' }
    }
    if (data.item.price< 10) {
       return { class: 'text-success' }
    }
}
```

This will add `class="text-error"` or `"text-success"` to each cell (`td`) of rows which item match the condition.

There is too a **`row-props`** property, working exactly the same way, but is adding the class to the row (`tr`) instead of cell.

Sources :

- https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/18589
- https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTable.tsx

Comment: Only this solution worked for me. It seems that other solutions with `item-class` don't work with Vuetify 3.