# How can I make use of item-class in v-data-table to increase the font-size?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm relatively new to VueJs and have attempted to update the font size to 20px in my v-data-table items (Vuetify 2). While doing so, I came across item-class. This approach was successful for changing the color, as demonstrated in [Vuetify data table :item-class doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969944/vuetify-data-table-item-class-doesnt-do-anything)  but it didn't work for adjusting the font size. Are there any special considerations that need to be taken into account for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/user1108/pen/VwRKrZW

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="dessertHeaders"
  :items="desserts"
  :single-expand="singleExpand"
  :expanded.sync="expanded"
  item-key="name"
  item-class="someclass"
  show-expand
  class="elevation-1"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the inspector, you can see that the font size is determined by this rule:

```css
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td, 
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tfoot > tr > td, 
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > td {
    font-size: .875rem;
    ...
}
```

If you want to change font size, you have to declare a rule with a higher specificity (see mdn for [details about specificity in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)), or override specificity by using [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important).

The item-class is set on the `tr`, so a rule for a `my-large-font` class could look like this:

```css
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr.my-large-font > td {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

See how it works in the snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items"
            item-class="size"
          />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      headers: [
        {text: 'Id', value: 'id'}, 
        {text: 'Name', value: 'name'}, 
        {text: 'size', value: 'size'}
      ],
      items: Array.from({length: 15}, (_,i) => ({
        id: i, 
        name: 'Name '+i, 
        size: ['fs-8', 'fs-14', 'fs-26'][Math.random()*3|0],
      }))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr.fs-8 > td{ font-size: 8px;}
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr.fs-14 > td{ font-size: 14px;}
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr.fs-26 > td{ font-size: 26px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```